# Sort List<int> ">" and "<"

Tags: c#, list, sorting

How do I sort a `List<int> {1,4,2,56,7}` from smallest to largest and largest to smallest? I have tried a few things, like

```
List<int> sorted = Listname.Sort();
```

and

```
List<int> sorted = Listname.OrderByDescending();
```

but I don't understand the syntax completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var smallToLarge = Listname.OrderBy(x => x);

var largeToSmall = Listname.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

If you want to assign them to a list, like in the code sample in your question, you'll have to call `.ToList()` after each one.

Comment: don't quite understand linq... can't getthis to work properly :(

Comment: ok nevermind I was just entering it wrong somehow. I just cut and paste this directly and it worked. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 2, 56, 7 };
            listOfInts.Sort();
            foreach (int ii in listOfInts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", ii);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Descending ...");
            listOfInts.Reverse();
            foreach (int ii in listOfInts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", ii);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I'm missing a step, because this just returned `1,4,2,56,7` and `7,56,2,4,1`

Comment: You must have missed the line that sorted the list.   listOfInts.Sort()

Answer (score 0):

To sort by ascending and descending

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 2, 56, 7 };
ints.Sort(); // by asc
ints.Reverse(); //by desc
```